# What is the fastest algorithm for 4x4 matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices

I was wondering wich is the faster algorithm for multiplication of 2 4x4 matrices. 
I read about **Strassen** but before implementing it (as is costly) I want to be sure I'm not leaving better ones behind.

Comment: What's wrong with just multiplying them using the definition? $4\times 4$ is pretty small.

Comment: That algorithm is good for Large matrices. For a $4\times4$ matrix it will add significant overhead.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "a 2010 study found that even a single step of Strassen's algorithm is often not beneficial on current architectures, compared to a highly optimized traditional multiplication, until matrix sizes exceed 1000 or more, and even for matrix sizes of several thousand the benefit is typically marginal at best (around 10% or less)." https://www.ics.uci.edu/~paolo/Reference/paoloA.ishp-vi.pdf

Comment: A $4 \times 4$ matrix is too small. To speed up such a calculation for this size in real life, you better manually unwind the for loop and inline the matrix access operations. Any  branching in your code will stall the pipeline of the floating point unit and the "relative" penalty can be very high for calculation of this size.